# Apresentar o valor dos vetores em C

Tags: c

Boa tarde,

Sou iniciante e estou criando um programa com 3 vetores e gostaria que o valor digitado me demonstrasse em tela, mas ao executar o mesmo apresenta alguns valores que não digitei.

Poderiam me ajudar:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()

{

  int i, A[i], c[i], mult=0, ctrl;
  char b[i];
  char comb;


i=0;
A[i]=0;
c[i]=0;
ctrl=0;

printf("Quantos vendas foram realizadas? : ");
scanf("\n%d", &ctrl);

//Entrada de dados



  for (i=0; i < ctrl; i++)
{

    printf("Digite a quantidade em Litros: ");
    scanf("\n%d", &A[i]);
    printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, A[i]);

    printf("Digite o tipo do combustível: ");
    scanf("\n%c", &b[i]);
    printf("b[%d] = %c\n", i, b[i]);    

    printf("Digite o valor: ");
    scanf("\n%d", &c[i]);
    printf("c[%d] = %d\n", i, c[i]);  

    }
    for (i=0; i < ctrl; i++)
    {
    mult = A[i] * c [i];
    printf("i = %d valor multi: %d\n", i, mult);
    }    

    //Imprimindo os valores do vetor
    for (i=0; i < ctrl; i++)
    {
    printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, A[i]);
    printf("b[%d] = %c\n", i, b[i]);
    printf("c[%d] = %d\n", i, c[i]);

    }



}
```

Comment: Pode dizer mais o que deseja e qual é o problema?

Comment: `int i, A[i], c[i]`, qual deveria ser o tamanho do vetor aqui?

Comment: Deverá indicar se quer usar memória estática ou dinâmica, caso seja memória estática então basta alterar o I e colocar um valor `A[50]` `C[50]` porque ao definirmos uma variável temos de alocar a memória, caso seja pelo método estático como está tentando fazer

Answer (score 0):

Isso devia retornar segmentation fault (caso i seja 0)

O i não tem valor inicial (i é um valor qualquer) se for 0 então está a trabalhar com um vetor nulo, se for 1 então está a trabalhar com um vetor de 1 posição.

Se fazer:

```
int i, A[i];
```

i tem um valor aletório porque é alocado num local aletório em memória, ou seja, um programa anterior que tenha usado aquela posição pode ter libertado o espaço (sem o limpar) e ter deixado o valor 5000, fazendo com que tenha um vetor de 5000 posições.

Assim o correto seria:

```
int i, A[100], c[200];...
```

Comment: Atenção que o que está a fazer é chamado Açucar sintático. Está a usar uma abordagem de memória dinâmica com memória estática. O compilador transforma `int i = 5, A[i]` para `int i =  5, *A; A = (int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int));` A segunda abordagem é a correta para memória dinâmica.